# 2.4GHz WiFi channel selection when all the non-overlapping channels are crowded

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

For 2.4GHz wifi, if the non-overlapping 1-6-11 channels all fully crowded by neighbors, should I select from the other overlapping channels (2,3,4,7.. etc.) or even so select the least crowded from 1-6-11?

Note: I have no option for upgrading to 5GHz for now.

Comment: possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/443178/is-it-better-to-use-a-crowded-2-4ghz-wi-fi-channel-1-6-11-or-unused-3-4-8?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is suggested to select form the least crowded of the 1-6-11
Source ([Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150502223736/http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/technology/channel/deployment/guide/Channel.html))
If you go with anything else, you can seriously reduce overall bandwidth.

Does your Wireless Router not have that the option of auto channel select?

(Summary of the Link Provided)

> Test Results
>
> Cisco performed tests to see the interference in a four-channel
>   environment. The tests were conducted with four Cisco Aironet 1200
>   access points and four Cisco Aironet 350 clients, all running 802.11b
>   at 11 Mbps. To help simulate the physical separation between devices,
>   the access points and clients were set at 5-mW transmit power and
>   spaced about 10 feet apart.
>
> The throughput was measured by the average of all four clients
>   simultaneously passing a 50-MB file five times. In all combined tests
>   there was one client to each of the four access points. In the
>   stand-alone test for benchmark comparisons, all four access points and
>   all four clients were on. However, only one client was in the process
>   of sending a 50-MB file using FTP.
>
> Testing included two different scenarios:
>
> 1. Four North American access points, two using channel 1, the third using channel 6, and the fourth using channel 11
>
> Note In this model, the first two access points had to share the RF
>   because they were on the same channel.
>
> 2. Four North American access points using channels 1, 4, 8, and 11
>
> Table 1 displays the results of the two tests. Note that even when two
>   access points shared channel 1, the overall performance was greater
>   than in the four-channel scenario. This is because the CSMA protocol
>   created a holdoff when the clients on the same channel decoded that
>   the interference was another 802.11 signal. In the four-channel
>   scenario, the client could not decode the interfering signal, reacted
>   as if it was low-level noise rather than a holdoff, and sent the
>   packet. This resulted in a collision and a retransmission on both
>   clients.
>
> Table 1 Result Summary Showing Average Throughput per Client
>
> Channels / Throughput (KB)
>  1, 1, 6, and 11 / 601.1 
>  1, 4, 8,
>   and 11 / 348.9
>
> Conclusion
>
> Many have long recommended a three-channel approach to provide
>   nonoverlapping channels. We still recommend such installations for
>   2.4-GHz WLANs, for both 802.11b and 802.11g technologies. A four-channel scheme can cause severe issues when the system is brought
>   online and the number of users starts to increase.
>
> In a four-channel design, the signal of one device is noise to another
>   device. Even in a design where a channel 1 cell would never overlap a
>   channel 4 cell, for example, you must still account for clients
>   transmitting that are not in the same location as the access point. By
>   looking at only the access points, you are ignoring the majority of
>   radios in your network. Virtually all new radio deployments support
>   802.11g and/or 802.11a and thus OFDM, which has much more sideband energy than 802.11b.
>
> If you design a system with four channels, the risk of interference
>   between cells greatly increases, resulting in poor performance and
>   lower throughput. As the volume of users and bandwidth needs increase,
>   problems will slowly arise, making it necessary to resolve the issue
>   at a later date. Start by using three nonoverlapping, noninterfering
>   channels.

Comment: Could you add a explanation to your answer about why it is suggested to select the least crowded of the 1.6.11 just in case the link every breaks.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive criticiziam and it is now updated

Comment: Thank you very much for offering help and updating your answer. This makes your answer valid even if the links break. Take my upvote.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing" class="soup-https-fixed). You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: Thank you, I am sure I have a lot to learn in the posting process, I will read this over

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As a result, we can't see any scenario that is recommended to select overlapping channels. Then, why are they made? :) EDIT: And sure I can go with the auto select mode but won't it cause live channel switchings and connection problems?

Comment: @BurakKalkan Yes auto mode will cause problems. For optimal perfomance my answer might give you a better understandable solution.

Comment: As RamonRobben said Auto could cause issues, considering your area being crowded and god knows how many clients, her answer does provide great insight to knowing what is around you, Wifi Analyzer is a great tool for any network admin, Not only do you know what Channels are being over used, you can see by what degree (strength), so it is finding a balance to what one of the three are used least and where the strongest are, it may be better in some cases to use the one of the three channels that has a lot of weak signals in your location, verse one that has the least.

Comment: Also note that in some cases Either of those may not work, as depending on the number of clients using each Channel also (and the amount of traffic being generated), There are tools out there that can see the number of clients on particular channels, then you know what at least some idea of the volume, when it comes down to it, this is really a try and wait and test over time, try another, wait, and test over time, till you find the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

Crowded Wi-Fi channels are never a good thing.

If you have 2.4 Ghz and no option to upgrade to 5 Ghz you are better off setting your channel to one that has the least overlapping. You can do this in your router interface.

Using an app called Wifi analyzer you can see which channels are currently overlaped.

[image]

You can get to your router by entering the default gateway address into your webbrowser. You can find this address by starting cmd and typing ipconfig and then enter. Here is a router interface with the channel option. You need to change this to a channel that has the least overlapping.

[image]

Setting the option to Auto will do a pretty good job. It will automatically switch to different channels and can sometimes get into a crowded channel. I find it better for myself to be able to check channels and change it every now and then If I experience wifi issues.

p.s if you have external wifi adapters some of them may not be able to reach you at a different channel. e.x my adapter didnt see my network when it was on channel 11 or higher. Its just something to keep in mind.