# Vey flaky *internal* WiFi connectivity

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Home network, a lot of Android, Windows, Linux devices. Outside connection is a Touchstone TG2492LG, also on the net an Epson L4160 network printer (all WiFi). Internet connection works fine, but connection between devices (e.g. to the printer) is intermittent at best. Works fine a while, then they are completely gone (printer can be managed by HTTP, get "no route to host", no ping/ssh to other Linuxes on the internal net, Internet works fine all the time).

There are no configuration changes in between, everything is up to date. Search turns out empty/irrelevant (lots on lost Internet connectivity, nothing on internal network working intermittently).

**Edit:** Further details: WiFi router (AP) is using 2.4GHz, no channel collisions with nearby networks (set to auto, anyway). I have Linux boxes 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.23, printer 192.168.0.6, all WiFi, same network (there is only one). Intermittent (at best) ping  between Linuxes or to printer, Internet connection from Linuxes works fine throughout (would need to connect to the printer --via WiFi-- to check if it has Internet connectivity). Internal connections work fine *sometimes* (could ssh to a Linux from my phone yesterday), most of the time they don't work at all.

Comment: Make sure you have one subnet, nor multiple (especially keep wireless on same subnet), give your printer a static IP on the subnet (lest it gets lost). Organize along these lines and see if that helps flaky connections.

Comment: Check https://superuser.com/a/1551115/346288 - might give some things to look for, and a tool to begin diagnosing.

Comment: @Hannu, thanks for the pointer. But my problem is that the *internal* network doesn't work at all (e.g. no ping to the --working-- Linux PC at 192.168.0.23, Internet connection --through WiFi router 192.168.0.1-- works with no problems. Both from here --192.168.0.3-- and the other Linux box.

Comment: @John, one WiFi net, no "networks separation" for "security" enabled, everything uses 2.4GHz. Printer gets discovered without trouble by Fedora, even if it changes IP address.

Comment: Maybe try a better, stronger Wireless Router / Access Point with more uniform coverage.

Comment: @John, not possible. The box is provided by my ISP, and can't be changed. Anyway, the problem is *not* general WiFi (exactly the same when sitting next to that box), just the internal network fails. OK, if somebody suggests it is a *router* problem, and provides a solution, I might be able to coax my ISP into fixing it...

Comment: You can add a Wireless Access point to your ISP's box and disable wireless on the ISP box. I do this and the results are much better.

Comment: @John, might be true. But that is extra cost and hassle to get what I'm already paying for. Besides, with everything in lockdown here, the chances of getting said hardware into my grubby hands are slim to nil. And nothing guarantees the result won't be exactly the same. I want to *know* the root cause.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "internal" wireless network. Please rethink the words you use to describe your situation.

Comment: @music2myear, internal, private, network. Behind the router, indoors.

Comment: That's just a wireless network. Nothing "internal" about it. Your incorrect use of words is making your question more difficult to understand than it ought to be. Just call it a wireless network, because that is what it is. Your problem is limited (in your mind) to the wireless LAN (the local area network).

Comment: @music2myear, then please edit to clarify. And the problem *is* just on the WLAN, connection through the router to the wider Internet **does** work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed (it seems). For an unrelated network problem my ISP updated the router's firmware, and the problem is gone (as far as I can see).